# Basic crypto functions in C++ (Mac OS X Mavericks, XCode 5)

Tags: cocoa, cryptography, aes, rsa, md5

I have been trying for a while to do some basic cryptography on my Mac OS X Mavericks. I would need MD5, SHA256, AES and possibly also RSA.
I need to develop in C++ but I only need a terminal application with Xcode.  I DON'T need to do anything on iPhone. I have a very basic configuration and I am not an expert. I tried crypto++ and OpenSSL, both gave me immense lists of errors at build time.
Thanks!

Comment: What is your actual question ?

Comment: Well... how do I do that? I just need something simple and working. Could you point me to some library that will just work without having to struggle for days?

Comment: You know you already have `/usr/lib/libcrypto` in OS X by default already ? No need to install or build anything. Type `man crypto` to get started.

Comment: Just so you know I wouldn't suggest using md5 in practice. It is hopelessly broken now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple supplies several encryption Technologies Specific to OS X: [General information](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html).

[CommonCrypto](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CommonCrypto), a C-level API that can perform most symmetric encryption and decryption tasks
CDSA/CSSM—a legacy API that should be used only to perform tasks not supported by the other APIs, such as asymmetric encryption.

[Security Transforms](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/SecTransformPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010801) API—a Core-Foundation-level API that provides support for signing and verifying, symmetric cryptography, and Base64 encoding and decoding.

There is also OpenSSL, it is useful for many command line operations but is no longer provided by Apple mainly due to the incompatibilities between versions.

CommonCrypto is supported by both OSX and iOS, this is what I generally use.  Security Transforms are OSX only and the newer technology. There are many examples of CommonCrypto usage on SO as well as libraries in GitHUb.

My suggestion is CommonCrypto, it is a "C" library so there should be no problem using it from C++.